# better understand ODBC ODBC Driver

Tags: odbc

If I give a sql statement `'select * from"` what is the role of ODBC and ODBC driver in getting the data back to for eg: datatable?

I also wanted to know why there is not a standard driver which can be used for all DMBSs?
Is it possible to have a standard ODBC driver which can be used seamlessly across any databases engines? 
Is there a big difference between different drivers in terms of its operations?

Even if I did not do ay extensive research on the topic. I did some googling before puting this post. Also I had to use separate DB s in my app, so I find it difficult to pack each driver software along with it. That is why I was looking for a better understanding

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of ODBC is it provides the standard API that lets you write your app in such a way that drivers can be added at a later date (by the user, not having to be shipped with your app). The role of the driver is to map the standard ODBC api to the database specific database api/network interface. So no, a standard driver for all databases would miss the point, you would need a further layer below the meta driver to actually talk to the database.

Comment: thanks Nick; why i was wondering was generally database will have a command line utility or a UI interface to do all the operations and it doesnt seem using a driver.if an end user/programmer could have used the same functionality it would have reduced a lot of hassles in distributing etc.. i suppose

Comment: Also do you know any good resource for a diagramatic rep. for the relation between ado, odbc, odbc driver etc.. though I did some search i coudnt find any good articles. sorry for troubling